# C#.net, Error in Updating Database through store procedure

Tags: c#

### **Hello! I'm c#.net beginner!**

```
**my Store procedure:**
```

> ```
> USE [DB_COUNTERINTELLIGENCE]
> GO
> /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Updatederogatory]    Script Date: 2015/6/12 1:21:24 AM ******/
> SET ANSI_NULLS ON
> GO
> SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
> GO
> -- =============================================
> -- Author:        <Author,,Name>
> -- Create date: <Create Date,,>
> -- Description:   <Description,,>
> -- =============================================
> ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Updatederogatory]
>   @ID int,
>   @txtid int,
>   @Firstname varchar(30),
>   @Middlename varchar(30),
>   @Lastname varchar(30),
>   @Company varchar(50),
>   @Department varchar(40),
>   @Position varchar(40),
>   @Violation text,
>   @DateCommitted date,
>   @TimeCommitted nchar(10),
>   @Remarks text,
>   @Activities text,
>   @Violation2 text,
>   @DateCommitted2 date,
>   @TimeCommitted2 nchar(10),
>   @Remarks2 text,
>   @Activities2 text,
>   @Violation3 text,
>   @DateCommitted3 date,
>   @TimeCommitted3 nchar(10),
>   @Remarks3 text,
>   @Activities3 text,
>   @Images image
>
> AS
> BEGIN
>   SET NOCOUNT ON;
> ```
>
> UPDATE tbl_derogatory SET  Firstname = @Firstname, Middlename =
>   @Middlename, Lastname = @Lastname,    Company = @Company, Department =
>   @Department, Position = @Position, Violation = @Violation,
>   DateCommitted = @DateCommitted,   TimeCommitted = @TimeCommitted,
>   Remarks = @Remarks, Activities = @Activities, Violation2 =
>   @Violation2, DateCommitted2 = @DateCommitted2,    TimeCommitted2 =
>   @TimeCommitted2, Remarks2 = @Remarks2, Activities2 = @Activities2,
>   Violation3 = @Violation3, DateCommitted3 = @DateCommitted3,
>     TimeCommitted3 = @TimeCommitted3, Remarks3 = @Remarks3, Activities3 =
>   @Activities3, Images = @Images WHERE ID = @txtid END

```
**Here is my code:**

    > if (txtid.Text == "")
    >             {
    >                 MessageBox.Show("Require ID is a must, Please Registered again for your ID", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
    > MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    >             }
    >             else if (txtfirstname.Text == "")
    >             {
    >                 MessageBox.Show("Your name is missing", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    > 
    >             }
    >             else if (txtlastname.Text == "")
    >             {
    >                 MessageBox.Show("Your Last name is missing", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    >             }
    >             else if (txtmiddlename.Text == "")
    >             {
    >                 MessageBox.Show("Your Middle name is missing", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    >             }
    >             else
    >             {
    >                 try
    >                 {
    >                     byte[] img = null;
    >                     FileStream fs = new FileStream(imageLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    >                     BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    >                     img = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
    > 
    >                     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
    >                     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    >                     cmd.Connection = con;
    >                     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    >                     cmd.CommandText = "Updatederogatory";
    >                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtid.Text);
    >                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", txtfirstname.Text);
    >                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Middlename", txtmiddlename.Text);
    >                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", txtlastname.Text);
    >                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", combocompany.Text);
    >                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", comboDepartment.Text);
    >                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position", txtposition.Text);
    > 
    >                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Violation", richviolation.Text);
    >                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateCommitted ", datecommitted.MaxDate);
    >                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeCommitted", timecommitted.Text);
    >                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks", richremarks.Text);
    >                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Activities", richderoactivities.Text);
    > 
    >                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Violation2", richviolation2.Text);
    >                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateCommitted2", datecommitted2.MaxDate);
    >                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeCommitted2", timecommitted2.Text);
    >                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks2", richremarks2.Text);
    >                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Activities2", richactivities2.Text);
    > 
    >                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Violation3", richviolation2.Text);
    >                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateCommitted3", datecommitted2.MaxDate);
    >                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeCommitted3", timecommitted2.Text);
    >                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks3", richremarks2.Text);
    >                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Activities3", richactivities3.Text);
    >                     con.Open();
    >                     cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Images", img));
    >                     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    >                     con.Close();
    >                     MessageBox.Show("Successfully Updated");
    >                 }
    >                 catch (Exception ex)
    >                 {
    > 
    >                     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    >                 }
```

}

My problem is when i Click update button, Message box will popup and write the error "Empty Path Name is not Legal"..

How to solve this?

Comment: what is the value of `imageLocation` variable?

Comment: imageLocation is not proper, try to navigate the imageLocation path manually, check whether it exists on machine .

Comment: the value of imagelocation variable is string

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because the variable "imageLocation" has not been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(imageLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

you probably don't have a string (you have empty one) inside the `imageLocation`